# Two combinatorics questions

Tags: combinatorics

I would like help on these questions please:

1). How many numbers between 1 and 99999 have a digit sum of 7?

2). How many numbers between 1 and 100 are prime?

In 1 I thought of representing all the numbers as a string of 5 digits, with zeros allowed when the number is less then 99999... But didn't know how to continue from there.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), call the digits of the five-digit number $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_5$ and solve the equation $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_5=7$ using [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

For (2), you can either go through the numbers up to 100 and see which ones can be factorized. The ones that can't, are prime. Or you can use another approach, like the [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for example.

Comment: For (1), is it equivelant to asking how many ways can you put 7 stars between 5 bards? so it's (5+7-1)C(7)=330 numbers their sum digit is 7?

Comment: @charlie That's exactly right. Now do the same for four, three, two and one variables. (Of course, with just one digit, there is only one solution).

Comment: Wait, didn't my solution covered all of the options from 00001 to 99999?

Comment: @charlie Oh, you're right. Very good! MY bad. I will edit my answer.